# How important is the master thesis work while applying for a PhD abroad?

Tags: phd

I did my Master's in chemistry (overall CGPA 8.5). My master thesis was not well written. I want to work on a different field during my PhD. Will my master thesis be an obstacle for my PhD application?

Comment: What country did you do the degree? What country do you want to study in?

Comment: i did my masters from india. i want to apply for phd in germany, japan and USA.

Comment: Was the writing the problem or the research itself? And a GPA of 8.5 is pretty high, what was the grade for the thesis?